# We've gone public

Tags: discussion

Looks like we've made it to public beta

A big Thank You and Congratulations to everyone in our community

Now we have to see it through to graduation

[image]

Here are our currents stats

Please have a look at them and think about how we can improve our numbers

They were good enough for us to make it through private beta but we seriously need to upgrade them to get through the public phase

We have made it this far, and I am still hopeful about our site

Let's all work together and get our site to graduation